# Node JS + Mongoose: saving documents inside while()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am just playing around with Node and Mongoose and I am curious about the following issue:

I am trying to save documents to mongo from within a loop / interval.

The following works just fine:

```
setInterval(function(){

    var doc = new myModel({ name: 'test' });

    doc.save(function (err, doc){
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        doc.speak();
    });

}, 1);
```

The following does not work:

```
while(true){

    var doc = new myModel({ name: 'test' });

    doc.save(function (err, doc){
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        doc.speak();
    });

}
```

What is the explanation for this behavior? The save callback is never firing in scenario 2

Additionally, can someone comment on best practices for building "long running workers"? I am interested in using node to build background workers to process queues of data. Is a while() a bad idea? setInterval()? Additionally, I plan to use the forever module to keep the process alive

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Node.js is single threaded so `while(true)` will fully occupy the single thread, never giving the `doc.save` callback a chance to run.

The second part of your question is too broad though, and you should really only ask one question at a time anyway.

Comment: Cool - thanks for that. Your answer led me to reading several additional articles on the single-threaded nature of Node; makes perfect sense that the infinite while() would block this thread from executing the other "queued" function calls.